# how to convert format of json response in php

Tags: php, json

I used array to get data in for loop ,i am getting json response like

```
 "subscription_id": [
        [ {
                "subscription_id": "25",
                "venue_id": "21"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "subscription_id": "26",
                "venue_id": "3"
            }
        ],
    ],
```

But I want response like

```
"subscription_id": [
            {
                "subscription_id": "25",
                "venue_id": "21"
            },
            {
                "subscription_id": "26",
                "venue_id": "3"
            },
    ],
```

Comment: share php code from where you return this json response ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Towsif is right - You basically have an array of one dimensional arrays with objects. As another solution, if you don't want to run a loop in a loop - something like this would let you:

- Access just the first key `subscription_id` with PHP's [`key()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) function
- Loop through the child arrays [by reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)
- Then run [`array_shift()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) on them to extract the object inside it.

I've also turned it into a handy-dandy little function, and tried to comment it along the way:

```
function extract_subarray_objects( $json ){
    // Turn the JSON to an object and extract the first key
    $key = key($decoded = json_decode( $json ) );

    // Loop the key's array children
    foreach( $decoded->$key as &$array ){
        $array = array_shift( $array ); // Extract the object inside
    }

    // re-encode and give it back.
    return json_encode( $decoded );
}
```

So just take your JSON response string:

```
$json_response = '{
    "subscription_id":
    [
        [
            {
            "subscription_id": "25",
            "venue_id": "21"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
            "subscription_id": "26",
            "venue_id": "3"
            }
        ]
    ]

}';
```

Pass it through our little function:

```
$json = extract_subarray_objects( $json_response );
```

And now your final `$json` variable is nice and clean, like your example:

```
{
    "subscription_id": [{
        "subscription_id": "25",
        "venue_id": "21"
    }, {
        "subscription_id": "26",
        "venue_id": "3"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as following way:

```
$json_response = '{
    "subscription_id":
    [
        [
            {
            "subscription_id": "25",
            "venue_id": "21"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
            "subscription_id": "26",
            "venue_id": "3"
            }
        ]
    ]

}';

$decode_json_response = json_decode($json_response, true);

foreach ($decode_json_response as $key => $values) {
   foreach ($values as $k => $v) {
       $new['subscription_id'][] = $v[0];
   }
}

$final_output = json_encode($new);
```

Output as you wanted:

```
{
    "subscription_id": [
        {
            "subscription_id": "25",
            "venue_id": "21"
        },
        {
            "subscription_id": "26",
            "venue_id": "3"
        }
    ]
}
```